# Getting the value of an uncontrolled Material UI TextField

Tags: material-ui

From [the documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled), it describes having an uncontrolled field by omitting the `value` and `onChange` attribute. The [React website](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) says to use a `ref` on any uncontrolled inputs, but doing this with a TextField only refs its container, a div. What is the recommended way of retrieving the value of an uncontrolled TextField in Material UI? I could use a `querySelector` to find the element, but that doesn't seem like a proper way.

Answer (score 4):

use `inputRef` prop on TextField

```
<TextField inputRef={ref} ... />
```

you can access its value by this: `ref.current.value`

Answer (score 3):

A clarification: `value` deals with controllability, and `onChange` deals with observability. They are separate from each other.

You only make inputs controlled by [setting the `value` prop](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/). Setting the `onChange` prop can be used separately to observe the input changes without acquiring control over it, thus, achieving what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

The way to provide a ref to the rendered input is via the `innerRef` prop on the TextField component. [Here's the a link](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) to the API where it states that. From there you can access the value of the input as such, `ref.current.value`

```
<TextField innerRef={ref} />
```